# What tools and how to approach Data Migration testing?

Tags: test-data, quality-assurance, quality-assessment, data-quality, data

What free automation tools exist for Data Migrations between Old and New Systems?

What approaches should I use to ensure data was migrated correctly ?

I'm a beginner Tester in web applications, E-Learning System.

Comment: Define "best".  Cheapest?  Best for integration ? Runs on Windows ?  please post some requirements.  Like which systems / databases.  There is no generic solution, just specific ones depending on platforms.

Comment: Also consider asking for 'good' instead of 'best'.  We're moving towards 'good practices' over 'best practices' in the industry and I believe this applies to tools too.

Comment: Thank you , DataBase is Sql / El-learning systems web appliaction..

Comment: Also, please help me to know what is the requirements, developer must provide me to start Testing? I must have two databases right?? one for old system the another to new system right?

Comment: What is "El-learning systems web application" ?  Please give more details.

Comment: You'll need examples of data from the old system and examples of what it should look like when converted to the new system.  Mainly you should be sitting down in meetings with the developer or dev team and figure out together what the requirements really are.  Otherwise you will spend a lot of time coming up with a solution only to find out you've solved the wrong problems and not the right ones.

Comment: If you are a beginner are you seeking this knowledge for general education?  Performing Quality Assurance on Data Loading with Automated  Tests is not solved with one  "question and answer on Stack Exchange".  You'll need to read a book.  Or two.

Comment: See ETL testing within https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-1-4302-0528-9_16

Comment: Great details also at http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/etl-testing-data-warehouse-testing/